# Убрать элементы из списка

Tags: python

```
l = [1,2,3,3]

def func(l):
    for i in l:
        if i == 3:
            l.remove(i)
    return l

func(l)
```

> ```
> [1,2,3]
> ```

Почему функция не убирает все тройки?

Comment: В вашем случае нужно проходить список в обратном направлении, тогда удаление элементов не принесет проблем. Либо, создать новый список без 3

Comment: Потому что удаление происходит в цикле, при изменении его длины происходят такие вещи.

Comment: ну то есть питон в цикле берет элемент с индексом 2 только один раз и вторую тройку которая встает на место первой просто не видит, правильно?

Answer (score 8):

Вы проходите через *тот же список, из которого вы удаляете элементы.*

Здесь постепенное состояния списка и актуальная позиция (как `^`):

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 3]      # перед входом в цикл
  ^

l = [1, 2, 3, 3]      # 1-ая итерация
     ^

l = [1, 2, 3, 3]      # 2-ая итерация
        ^

l = [1, 2, 3, 3]      # 3-ая итерация — элемент на актуальной позиции удалится
           ^

l = [1, 2, 3]         # актуальная позиция за концом списка — цикл окончается
              ^
```

Answer (score 7):

Потому что не стоит изменять итерируемую коллекцию. Задача идеально решается списковым включением:

```
[i for i in l if i != 3]
```

Comment: `list(filter(lambda i: i != 3, your_l))` ?

Comment: Можно и так. Я в python предпочитаю использовать включения, так как Гвидо не единожды заявлял, что они идиоматичнее.

Answer (score 3):

Functional programming:

```
list(filter(lambda i: i != 3, your_l))
```

Comment: Можно поизвращаться и лямбду заменить на `(3).__neq__`)

Comment: @МихаилМуругов cool!

Comment: @МихаилМуругов *`(3).__ne__`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Да. Опечатался.