# Удалить словарь из списка словарей по значению одного из ключей

Tags: python, dict

Есть словарь

```
a = [{"animal": "cats", "color": "red yellow blue"}, 
     {"animal": "dogs", "color": "brown green black"},
     {"animal": "birds", "color": "purple white pink"},
...]
```

И есть список слов:

```
b = ["yellow", "black" ...]
```

Необходимо полностью удалить словарь из списка, если второй элемент значения ключа "color" находится в списке b.

То есть на выходе нужно получить такой список словарей:

```
a = [{"animal": "dogs", "color": "brown green black"},
     {"animal": "birds", "color": "purple white pink"},
...]
```

Пыталась реализовать следующим образом, но не получаю нужного результата:

```
for i in a:
    words = []
    for word in i['color'].split():
        words.append(word)

    if words[1] in b:
        del i
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, справиться с задачей

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Идём по списку `a`. Для каждого элемента этого списка (словарь `d`) берём значение по ключу `d["color"]`, разбиваем его `split()`, берём второй элемент `[1]` и проверяем что он не в списке `b`. Если это так, то весь словарь помещается в результарующий список `c`.

```
c = [d for d in a if d["color"].split()[1] not in b]
```

Answer (score 1):

Замените `i['word']` на `i['color']` (в словарях нет ключа `word`, вам нужен ключ `color`), а `del i` на `a.remove(i)` (вам нужно удалить словарь `i` из списка `a`).

PS. Но так делать не нужно, потому что если список достаточно большой и из него будет удаляться много элементов, [возникнут проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176639/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-remove-python).

Answer (score 0):

Ну и ещё вариант в формате вашего кода, только упрощённый и работающий:

```
for i,d in enumerate(a.copy()):
    if d['color'].split()[1] in b:
        del a[i]
```

- итерируемся по копии, чтобы не сломать итерацию
- удаляем элемент по индексу
- про более простую проверку вам уже все написали